# Create varchar using Entity Framework Core 2 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to use code first to generate my SQL Server 2014 database. The table columns get generated as nvarchar(MAX) but I want the strings to get generated as varchar(50).

Things I tried in my model:

```cs
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }


[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
public string Name { get; set; }


[Required]
[MaxLength(50)]
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
public string FName { get; set; }
```

This gets generated in the migration as:

```
Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false)
```

When using the "dotnet ef database update" the the columns get created as nvarchar(MAX).

I'm using references:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools Version="2.0.2"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet Version="2.0.1"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is working now with `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]`.

I think when I deleted the database tables and deleted the migration from the migrations table using SSMS, it was not actually deleting the tables so it appeared that they were getting created the same way as before with the `nvarchar(MAX)` when I refreshed the tables folder in SSMS.

So `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]` works fine.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue but I'm using Fluent API for configuration.
So, if you'd be willing to use Fluent to configure your model then:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<MyEntity>()
        .Property(x => x.Name)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false);
}
```

As EF now knows you don't need Unicode it'll use `VARCHAR` instead of `NVCHAR`.
This combined with `HasMaxLength` will result in your desired `VARCHAR(50)`.

Comment: Be aware that `HasMaxLength` works on EntityFrameworkCore.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not for the requested version, starting with EF Core 6, there is a dedicated option for specifying `VARCHAR` vs `NVARCHAR` as a column type with the `[Unicode(false)]` decoration.

Then you can separate out the length and column type definitions:

```
[Unicode(false)]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

A value of `true` is the default and will define NVARCHAR in SQL while `false` will set it to VARCHAR.  This setting will properly apply the correct column names for any supported database or ignore it for database types that do not use it.

see: [Entity Properties - Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#unicode)

Comment: It just work on EF 7.

Answer (score 1):

For those who looking for `EF6` (I mean the Entity Framework not the Core) you can use `HasColumnType()`, like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Property(x => x.PhoneNumber).HasColumnType("varchar(max)");
}
```